# mySQL query works but in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join, outer-join

I am testing a LEFT OUTER JOIN query and it works without any issue when I run it directly in phpMyAdmin but when I run it in PHP, it does not execute.

Connection to thye DB is fine, I tired to print the query itself but page is blank, any ideas what might be wrong:

```
$sql_query  = "
SELECT k.id
     , k.keyword
     , k.model_id
     , k.series
     , v.id v_id
     , v.make
     , v.model
     , v.price
     , v.state
     , v.city
     , v.variant
     , v.reg_year
  FROM tbl_news_keywords k
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_vehicles v
    ON k.model_id = v.model
 WHERE k.type = 3
 GROUP 
    BY k.keyword
";

        $rs_query = $db -> Execute($sql_query);

        echo ($sql_query);
```

Comment: I`m guessing you need a prepare before execute

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @Mark Baker, I set `error_reporting(1);` but the page is still blank, I guess no errors there.

Comment: Setting error_reporting(1) won't help with fatal syntax errors, check the webserver logs

Comment: there is nothing in the apache logs either:(

Comment: As already explained, in the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate, and potentially erroneous.

Comment: @ Strawberry, removing GROUP BY doesn't help much either, except that in SQL I get rows I do not need.

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword can help with that. There is a caveat to all this (but I'll save that for another day)

Comment: You could check the error message after executing the query (`$db->error`, guessing you are using mysqli because in PDO the code above is incorrect).

Comment: do `var_dump` instead of `echo` you will get better information.

Comment: var_dump gives me the same query as the one in PHP or SQL. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: AS @Mihai says, it's missing the prepare before the execute. The code above is incorrect on mysqli and PDO, you should be getting a "Call to undefined method" error on `$db -> Execute($sql_query);`

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro, this is what I am looking at right now. All my other SQL statements are execute in this way, no issue there, just with this example. I tired to change `$rs_query = $db -> Execute($sql_query);` to `$rs_query = $db -> Prepare($sql_query);` and `$rs_query -> Execute();` but now I get error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object

Comment: I tried your code on my computer and it throws an error, but when I do the prepare-execute it works like a charm. maybe it's something on the `$db` variable, how do you do the connection to the database?

Comment: Here it is: `$db = ADONewConnection('mysql');
$db->Connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME) or die();`  and in the ADOdb Library: `if (ADODB_PHPVER >= 0x4300)
   $this->_connectionID = mysql_connect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword,
            $this->forceNewConnect,$this->clientFlags);` I know that mysql extension is deprecated and is something up to be changed but can this be the issue?

Comment: Why not echoing before execute? ` echo $sql_query; exit; //$rs_query = $db -> Execute($sql_query);`

Comment: var_dump($sql_query) gives me the same statement as the one in PHP file.

Comment: @RN Kushwaha, echoing the $sql_query gives me the exact same statement as the one which is given in the PHP between the "". What would that mean, the statement becomes corrupt on execution, probably because of the $db connection?